# GHashTable is not defined when attempting to retrieve it from GArray

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, glib

The compiler is saying that GHashTable is not defined but clearly it is defined if i am using it above the code that retrieves the GHashTables from the array. What is going on? I am confused.

```
gcc -Wall -o tht `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` TestGLib.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:31:0,
                 from TestGLib.c:5:
TestGLib.c: In function ‘main’:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:67:62: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct _GHashTable’
 #define g_array_index(a,t,i)      (((t*) (void *) (a)->data) [(i)])
                                                              ^
TestGLib.c:24:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘g_array_index’
         GHashTable *current_ht = g_array_index(g_arr_hts, GHashTable, i);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/garray.h:67:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘GHashTable {aka struct _GHashTable}’
 #define g_array_index(a,t,i)      (((t*) (void *) (a)->data) [(i)])
                                                              ^
TestGLib.c:24:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘g_array_index’
         GHashTable *current_ht = g_array_index(g_arr_hts, GHashTable, i);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
TestGLib.c:26:22: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
         printf("%s", (gchar) g_hash_table_lookup(current_ht, "key"));
                      ^
TestGLib.c:26:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s", (gchar) g_hash_table_lookup(current_ht, "key"));
                 ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 %d
```

The code i am attempting to compile is very simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main() {

    GHashTable *g_ht_first = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, free, free);
    g_hash_table_insert(g_ht_first, g_strdup("key"), g_strdup("val"));

    GHashTable *g_ht_second = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, free, free);
    g_hash_table_insert(g_ht_second, g_strdup("key"), g_strdup("val"));

    GArray *g_arr_hts = g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, 2);

    g_array_append_val(g_arr_hts, g_ht_first);
    g_array_append_val(g_arr_hts, g_ht_second);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < g_arr_hts->len; i++) {

        GHashTable *current_ht = g_array_index(g_arr_hts, GHashTable, i);

        printf("%s", (gchar) g_hash_table_lookup(current_ht, "key"));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you added `#include<glib.h>` or relevant headers?

Comment: Yeah, they are included, i am using GHashTable in other parts of the same function and even on the parameters of the function itself. I don't know what is going on. Am i inserting the GHashTables into the GArray incorrectly. But that does not make sense because the compiler says it can't find the GHashTable type.

Comment: Somehow some declarations are missing I suppose. Maybe you didn;t include. Maybe you can provide a more complete example

Comment: I just pasted the complete functions and files i am using

Comment: also just updated the complete compiler log which shows the make command i am using

Comment: ok so i abstracted my problem into a simpler form, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after going back to the docs, i noticed that Glib also has Pointer Array GPtrArray so i updated my code to that and it worked. Didn't know that the regular GArray does not support pointers. :)

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html

Comment: It's what is hidden behind the typedefs. `GArray`, e.g. `int *array` (glib handles the allocation), `GPtrArray`, e.g. `int **array`. One is an array of type, the other is more or less a pointer-to-pointer-to-type. Glib works quite well, but it does allocate quite a bit behind the scenes to do what it does.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for the clarification. So GArray handles non pointer variables and GPtrArray handles pointer variables.

Comment: Yes, see [Pointer Array](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html) (and also the page on arrays -- I just bookmark the Gtk & Glib References Index and keep them handy)